# BIRT Issue while using MultiSelect List Box

Tags: birt

I was supposed to use MultiSelect List Box (Dynamic one) where user can select multiple value (by holding Ctrl key) to see the report.

So while implementing I tried to fetch param value at **BeforeOpen** method and pass it to DataSet ,append it to where clause using IN operator.**I got SQL error on screen**. So when I print param value it was something like **[Ljava.lang.Object;@26ba26ba]** causing error in query. I thought I can't process that multiselect param value in script and pass it to query. So dropped that Idea.

Now I am using **BIRT's inbuilt Filter functionality in Data set**. What I was doing in SQL using script at **Beforeopen Method** now i am doing the same in dataset Filter. I used **row["dataColumn"]IN param["param"].value** and it is working fine. I am able to select one or multiple value from filter screen , execute report and getting proper result.

Now one more thing I need to implement is There should be Select All in filter list box so that instead of selecting any other value user can just select Select All and bring the report for all data. I am passing **'%'** against Select All. Since I am using IN operator so I am not able to get any data on Report.

I want to provide Select All functionality along with multiselection but not able to do that for above limitations . Alternatively I can use Ctrl+A to select all and it is working also I can do that but this is as per requirement that I need to implement.

I am using **BIRT version="3.2.17"**

ANY IDEA WILL BE APPRECIATED..Thanks In Advance..:)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to add a "Select All" option to your parameter choices?  I have done this using a union with my parameter query and just adding a 'Select All' to my query results.

Normally what I'll do is add something to my query that will let me easily replace the parameters.  Something like:

```
SELECT myStuff
FROM myTables
/**where**/
```

You can then modify your DataSet query in your beforeOpen statement.

Something along the lines of:

```
if(params["myParam"]!='Select All'){
    this.queryText=this.queryText.replace("/**where**/","WHERE myStuff IN ('" + params["myParams"].join("','") + "')");
}
```

This is obviously very simplified, but you should be able to use some form of it to allow what you are asking.